# Dynamic back link on a landing page in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a item page built in Angular 2 that is linked from an items list page. I am trying to add a 'back' link which takes the user back to the items list page restoring the previous URL with route params. That works fine with Location.back(). However, if a user lands on the items page via a deep link, there is no history in the Location object, so the Location.back() doesn't work. I tried the following, so if the back() function doesn't work, the app triggers the navigate() function, but it throws an error once the app navigates back to the items page:

```
clickGoToItemsPage() {
    this._location.back();
    this._router.navigate(['ItemsPage']);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

The error happens *after* the second function is triggered and the page is at the ItemsPage. Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question. 
You can catch the error from `this._location.back()` and then call `this._router.navigate(...)` instead. If `this._location.back()` succeeds, then `this._router.navigate(...)` is not executed. Is this what you want?

```
clickGoToItemsPage() {
    try {
      this._location.back();
    } catch() {
      this._router.navigate(['ItemsPage']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something like this. However, this._location.back() doesn't throw an error when there is no previous page so the function inside catch doesn't trigger. The page just doesn't respond.

Comment: I should point out, the error in the original question only appears when I have both functions without a try/catch statement.

    this._location.back();
    this._router.navigate(['ItemsPage']);

Comment: I don't get what you try to accomplish with this. Why would you call `router.navigate` after `_location.back()`. Why not just calling `_router.navigate()`?

Comment: Because _router.navigate() just takes me to the default target page, whereas _location.back() will take me back to the previous page with preserved routeparams that the user had previously. e.g. `http://originalpage/page-num/2`

Comment: Sure but what do you gain by calling `router.navigate()` afterwards? I think the end result would be the same.

Comment: Because if a user arrives at the page via a deep-link there is no history for the 'back' button or `_location.back()` to work. So the page just sits there. I was thinking that adding `_router.navigate()` after may trigger if the `_location.back()` function doesn't have anything to respond with.